# Retrieving source of of img element intermittently makes whole app disconnect from server

Tags: javascript, blazor

I set an image to my img in Blazor:

```
<InputFile @ref="inputFile" OnChange="@ShowPreview" />


<div class="fillContainer"> 
    <img id="capturedImage" onchange="@Checker()" style="max-width:200px;max-height:200px" @ref="previewImageElem" />
</div>

 public static string ImageResult; 

    private InputFile? inputFile;
    private ElementReference previewImageElem;

    private async Task ShowPreview() => await JS.InvokeVoidAsync(
        "previewImage", inputFile!.Element, previewImageElem);
```

This is all working fine. The image is displayed.

But when I now want to use the image, I am trying this:

```
private async Task Checker()
{
    var result = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("captureImage");

    if (result == null) return;
    if (result.Length < 20)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string output = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(',') + 1);
        ImageResult = output;
    }

}
```

but this most of the time fails here at the result part.

This function is behind this:

```
function captureImage() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var img = document.getElementById('capturedImage');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

This sometimes returns nothing, but most of the times disconnects the server connection and then re  connects again.
Every following js call then crashes and is never executed.

But on rare occasions it just works fine.

What am I missing here?